# how to mmap() a queue?

Tags: multithreading, process, queue, malloc, mmap

I have the following problem:

I have created a queue. The addition of elements (malloc) are done by the main() function, and I have created a thread, which will process the elements/datum and free them. 
This is a continuous process, and it will continue till I kill the process.

Now, if I kill the process the data in the queue will be lost, so I was thinking about implementing mmap() on it. So that the queue is also stored in a regular file, and when I restart the process the data will be reload into memory for further processing by the thread...

Since I am malloc'ing and free'ing memory, I suppose the mmapped file size will grow or reduce continuously.

Now is this possible to implement or should I consider other options???

Thanks.

EDIT1: can I use lseek or ftruncate() to resize file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly put a queue (or any other data structure) into `mmap()`ed memory instead of heap memory, but you will run in to several problems which you must overcome:

- You will have to do all of the memory management in the memory block corresponding to the `mmap()`ed file yourself. Unless your queue data structure is one monolithic block of memory, it probably has nodes and pointers which can get created, removed, and relocated. With heap memory you can delegate the task of allocating and freeing small blocks of memory to `malloc()` and `free()`, including reusing memory that has been freed for use by new nodes in your data structure. In your `mmap()`ed file you will have to do all of this yourself.
- You won't be able to use pointers inside your `mmap()`ed block of memory, only offsets from the start of the block. This is because if the block is detached and reattached in another process it probably won't be at the same memory address. Since data structure access is done using pointers, you will have the overhead of constantly transforming offsets to pointers and back by adding or subtracting the `mmap()` block's base address.
- If you want to be able to recover by reattaching the block in another process after the first process has been killed, you will have to be prepared for the case where the first process was killed in the middle of a critical section while one or more invariants of the data structure were temporarily violated. In other words, you might be reattaching a corrupt of inconsistent data structure. In order to support this fully correctly you will have to be very careful with the kinds of mutations you perform on your data structure.

All in all, my recommendation to you is that it's not worth it. You should use a fast, efficient, and easy to use data structure based in heap memory, and once in a while save a serialized snapshot to a regular file. If you have to receiver, recover from the last known good snapshot.